Designing AWS Network infrastructure for web scrapping
I am working on a web scrapping problem where I have to collect text data from the individuals web-pages of over 100K websites. We are hosting the entire infrastructure on AWS.
Current Implemented Solution :

We give the fargate task a set of domain homepages
It uses the focused_crawler() function from trafilatura to discover the links various urls of a website
Then we are using buffered_downloads() function from the same library to download the HTML of the webpage and extract the text content of the webpage.

Network Infrastructure of our design :

We are using the standard VPC design for our internet access
We are using a single VPC with 6 subnets(3 Public and 3 Private) to route our traffic

Problems Faced :

Some of the fargate tasks are taking too long to discovery the links or to download them(The webpage responses are taking too long from the server side)
This is causing some of the job to run for days (2-3 days) without any progress

Possible Issues :

Maybe the VPC is not able to handle traffic at such large scale
Or the servers have registered the VPC IP as a bot and are blocking the responses to the IP

Could someone give a better approach or design for the web-scrapper so that we can access more websites faster and download their webpage content in a reasonable SLA. BTW for all our web-scrapping tools we are following the website politeness rules.
Some solutions that I explored :

Using a SOCKS proxy server like dante-server to implement IP rotation

Using AWS HAProxy and Global accelerator for IP rotation and scalable scrapping solution




I am new to network engineering and have little idea of this domain. Any new suggestion or design is also welcome.
Thanks in advance

First of all, you need to localize the root cause:

Does the download speed(or throughput) change over time and is lower than usual for the problematic sites/pages? Try to download test data samples in parallel from the other domain. And add Mbit/s metric to monitor the target sites. It will help you to find out if the target sites limiting you or not. If so - try to spread the data flow among unique IPs. The basic principles can be found here datascrape.tech/blog/pyramid-of-efficient-scraping

2.Double-check the pages/URLs queue size. It might be that you have local maximums of URLs number and this causes the problem, not the network throughput.

Double-check that you haven't reached your VPCs throughput maximum. Haven't checked that recently, but usually
throughput(network speed) depends on the disk size and is limited by
default for the VPCs.

